# Eclipse: no stderr

Tags: mysql, eclipse, stderr

I'm working with Eclipse (Kepler) on MySQL and MariaDB. When I add a line like:

```
fprintf( stderr, "in fetch_line\n");
```

to one of my functions this output does not appear anywhere.

In the past the text appeared in the console of Eclipse but this disappeared somehow.

How can I reenable this?

Thanks
AugustQ

PS: this worked fine until it disappeared ome days ago. Looks like I did (un)mark the wrong checkbox but I could not find the correct one.